# CSS Transparent Bacground image showing background pattern

Tags: html, css

I have transparent background image and I simply added in html using this code,

```
<img src="profile1.png">
```

When this page is displayed image is showing its background pattern.
I want to show the background color not the pattern.
Am I missing something? Is it a browser issue?

[image: Transparent Background Image]

Comment: Well it's not transparent background then - You can actually see it in the picture you uploaded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is not transparent. The checkerboard pattern is part of it.

Comment: What about this one, commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Freelan-logo_backgroundless.png. If you click the image checkboard pattern is gone. Any reason for that?

Comment: @himu800804 That one uses this file: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Checker-16x16.png as a background image. When you click the image, you're seeing it by itself, without the checkerboard background being added by the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not browser issue.Pattern is part of this image. so it is showing in browse. You need to crop this image from Photoshop.

Comment: What about this one, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Freelan-logo_backgroundless.png. If you click the image checkboard pattern is gone. Any reason for that?

Comment: because it is transparent image. And pattern is not a part of image.

Comment: You have save image from Photoshop after disabling the background color layer. If you want to only image please see this link. http://www.microknowledge.com/remove-background-photoshop/